# How to save Windows Hibernation image

Tags: windows-vista, system-restore

I'm using Vista in my laptop and I want to save the file created when I hibernate the Laptop so that I can reuse to quickly get into same old state of my slow laptop.

Is there any utility for save and restore of this data?

Comment: Going back in time like this is an unusual request. If you switch back to a previous state, you will lose all the work you've done since the previous save. If you don't lose it, then the state of the running applications will be out of sync with the contents of the disk. I expect that will eventually lead to data loss. Why do you want to revert to an earlier state? Perhaps there's a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: You're joking. On my PC I restart once in a month - only when it is unavoidable. Otherwise I hibernate it daily.

Comment: Consider this: you have an open file (say in your word processor), you save a hibernate state, you then type something and save the file, then you restore the hibernate state which restores the state of the word processor data but doesn't change the state of the file on the disk, you type something else (say in another part of the document) and save the file. You've then written over the file from the first save and lost some data. Now perhaps you can keep track of this, but the same thing is likely to occur behind the scenes in other applications resulting in unpredictable data loss.

Comment: Your concern is justified. Have you really seen it happening? Because for example if Word is open and it's RAM contents is updated to old state due to hibernation but the file content is latest, are you saying that in that case Word is going to discard the disk file content and go for what is there in the RAM? Let me try with a external hard disk with a open file on it and changing its contents on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of the "Hibernate" is for users to be able to shutdown their pcs, and then resume it from where they left off with their apps, documents, etc

Trying to use a "hiberate point" to quickly get into same old state is a wrong approach as it doesnt fix the real issue at hand- a slow laptop..

And even if so, there is No tool or utility that will let you save those "hibernate" files and keep reverting back to that state..

If you have a slow laptop you need to fix the slowness.
If your laptop configuration/hardware is pretty old -that's the reason why its slow..

If however it is fairly new, then you need to look up on the net for quick fixes- Defragementing, Cleaning up old files, Removing unncessecary programs, etc etc

Vista also requires a fairly good configuration, Are you sure your Hardware is above the recomended config for Vista to run smoothly ?

Comment: There is another need. I've many programs, softwares, editors open which I need to open again after shutdown/restart which take away my 20 minutes or more time. I know that using disk image backup/restore software we can restore even the hibernate data but it'll be waste of time to restore whole C drive image. So restoring only hibernate image is what I need.